# MeasureText doesn't correspond to DrawText without TextFormatFlags.SingleLine, workaround?

Tags: winforms, gdi+

I want to measure text inside a rectangle, but it only works correctly when the format flags include TextFormatFlags.SingleLine.

Eg. Put a panel on a form and add this Paint event handler

```
    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.SingleLine | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter | TextFormatFlags.Left;
        Panel panel = (sender as Panel);

        //Draw the text
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, "hello", SystemFonts.DefaultFont, new Rectangle(0, 0, panel.Bounds.Width, panel.Bounds.Height), Color.Red, flags);

        //Draw a border around the panel
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(System.Drawing.Pens.Black, 0, 0, panel.Width - 1, panel.Height - 1);

        //Measure the text and draw a rect around it
        Size s = TextRenderer.MeasureText(e.Graphics, "hello", SystemFonts.DefaultFont, new Size(panel.Bounds.Width, panel.Bounds.Height), flags);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, 0, 0, s.Width, s.Height);


    }
```

you'll see this

[image: Working screenshot]

but if you take out SingleLine in the flags;

```
        TextFormatFlags flags =  TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter | TextFormatFlags.Left;
```

then you get this

[image]

I don't imagine that behaviour is by design, but either way, can I work around it easily?

Thanks

Comment: Curious what the downvote is for, yes I did solve my own problem, but it is still a valid problem others might encounter.  I'm not allowed to accept my own answer for 2 days...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, writing it out gave me the solution I needed.

```
    private Size FixMeasureText(Graphics graphics, string p, Font font, Size size, TextFormatFlags flags)
    {
        Size s = TextRenderer.MeasureText(graphics, p, font, size, flags);
        if ((flags & TextFormatFlags.SingleLine )== 0)//need to fix
        {
            s.Height = ((size.Height - s.Height) / 2 )+ s.Height;
        }
        return s;

    }
```

So if it really is a bug in TextRenderer.MeasureText, then the solution is just to use this method instead...